# my computer won't boot up from the cd

Tags: boot, software-installation

It also is built by myself. It is blank. I have tried from a usb and cd, nothing seems to work.  I have downloaded ubuntu live for my computer onto a blank cd.

Comment: You are not trying to run the ISO file? For either one you must burn the ISO - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 0):

You must burn the downloaded ISO to a DVD or a USB Flash Drive.  I believe that Lubuntu is the only version that will still fit on a CD.  Merely coping the download to a DVD or Flash Drive will not make it bootable.
1.  After the download is complete, you must check the MD5Sum to make sure that there were no errors in the download.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM 
and 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
2.  Then you have to burn it to a DVD or Flash Drive at the lowest possible speed.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto